# Strategic game with complete informaation

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium, dominant-strategy

Consider the following strategic game with complete information played
by three players. Each player $i ∈ {1, 2, 3}$ chooses her action from $A =
\{1, 2, . . . , 10\}$. Utility functions, mapping each action profile $(a_1, a_2, a_3) ∈ A^3$
into utils, of the three players are as follows:
$$u_1(a_1, a_2, a_3)=-|a_3-a_1|+|a_2-a_1|$$
$$u_2(a_1, a_2, a_3)=-|a_1-a_2|+|a_3-a_2|$$
$$u_3(a_1, a_2, a_3)=-|a_2-a_3|+|a_1-a_3|$$

The given solution is as follows:

Suppose $a_1 < a_3$. Straightforward argument shows that the
set of actions that constitute pure best response for player 2 is $\{1, . . . , a_1\}$.
When $a_1 > a_3$, the set is $\{a_1, . . . , 10\}$ and when $a_1 = a_3$, then the set is
$\{1, . . . , 10\}$.

This solution is too short for me to understand how to start solving it. I understand the conditions when one is >,< or = but I do not seem to follow how the BR is calculated

Comment: So you don't understand "*Suppose $a_1 < a_3$. Straightforward argument shows that the
set of actions that constitute pure best response for player 2 is $\{1, . . . , a_1\}$.*"? Have you tried substituting numbers to see if that makes it easier for you to understand? E.g., do you see why if $a_1 = 5, a_3 = 8$, and Player $2$'s payoff function is
$$u_2(5, a_2, 8)=-|5-a_2|+|8-a_2|$$
they would never play numbers larger than 5?

Comment: Ah I see. For the second case when $a_1>a_3$ then 2 would play 8 and up? if we assume $a_1=8$ and $a_3=5$

Comment: "*When $a_1 > a_3$, the set is $\{a_1, . . . , 10\}$*", so yes.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a specific self-study problem and was resolved in the comments.

Comment: If the OP has solved the question, they could answer it themselves so we have a completed Q and A instead of closing off the question?

Comment: @WalrasianAuctioneer See [answer](https://economics.stackexchange.com/a/50224/1601).

Comment: @Giskard I am slightly lost for words.

Answer (score 1):

The given solution is as follows:

Suppose $a_1 < a_3$. Straightforward argument shows that the
set of actions that constitute pure best response for player 2 is $\{1, . . . , a_1\}$.
When $a_1 > a_3$, the set is $\{a_1, . . . , 10\}$ and when $a_1 = a_3$, then the set is
$\{1, . . . , 10\}$.

Suppose we set $a_1=5$ and $a_3=3$ as in the case when $a_1>a_3$, as described in the comment as well
$$u_2(5, a_2, 3)=-|5-a_2|+|3-a_2|$$ then player 2 would be better playing from $\{a_1,....10\}$ and vice versa.